# ASP.NET MVC Busy Box Implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, busybox

I'm wondering if anyone has created a generic "busy box" type control for ASP.NET MVC.  Basically something that popups (disables the screen) while the page loads (or redirects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [JQuery Block UI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/). If you're using JQuery, this is a really easy thing to setup. Basically for all ajax requests, you just need to add the following lines:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $().ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
});
```